# GatsbyJS create page using different layout

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I've looked all over and can't find an answer to this. I'm creating a bunch of pages which is fine, but there's a few pages where I want to specify a different layout/html.js, where I can completely customise everything being output from the page (inc head). Using Helmet isn't enough for what I want to do.

Is there a way of telling createPage to not use html.js/default layout, and use something else?

Many thanks

Comment: Of course, there's a way to do it. Look into https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to filter out the pages you want in the gatsby-node.js file.
Essentially the query you are using to create those pages dynamically, break it up into two separate queries and on those queries create a filter.

So for example if you have a category field from your graphQL query or a specific slug that you want to use a particular layout that that is what you would filter for.

Here is an example graphQL query using ButterCMS that renders "ReactPosts" and "NonReactPosts"

```
{
  ReactPosts: allButterPost(filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {name: {eq: "React"}}}}) {
    nodes {
      id
    }
  }
  NonReactPosts: allButterPost(filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {name: {ne: "React"}}}}) {
    nodes {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

When you are creating the pages using *createPages* you will be using different components templates and those components will contain the different Layouts.

You would also need to call createPages for twice in this case, one for each post type, (react vs non react pages)